# Small circles at mesh nodes

Tags: plotting, mesh, style

How to show the (16 X 4) mesh intersection points by a tiny red dots?

```
ParametricPlot[v { Cos[u], Sin[u]},  {u, 0, 2 Pi},{v,1,3}, Mesh-> {15,3} ]
```

[image]

Comment: Narasimham, please consider reverting your latest edit, Your edit  makes the answers completely irrelevant (although all three answers do work for your original question). I suggest you post a new question for the 3D version of the problem.

Comment: Thanks, got it, will do..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
ParametricPlot[
    v {Cos[u], Sin[u]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, 1, 3}, 
    Mesh   -> {15, 3},
    Epilog -> {
        PointSize @ .02, Red, 
        Point @ Catenate @ Array[
            Function[{u, v}, v {Cos[u], Sin[u]}], 
            {15 + 2, 3 + 2}, 
            {{0, 2 Pi}, {1, 3}}
        ]
}]
```

[image]

As pointed by Shutao TANG, `Catenate` is new so one can replace it with `Flatten[#,1]&`.

Points on positive side of x axis are doubled since it is the beginning and the end of u domain. But I left them for generality, like `u -> {0, 1}` cases.

Answer (score 5):

Due to `Catenate[]` is a new function for V10, here is a solution for V9 or earlier version:

You just need to repalce `ParametricPlot[]` with `Table[]` and add the interval values `Pi/8` and `1` to generate the intersection coordinates.

```
Show[
 {ParametricPlot[v {Cos[u], Sin[u]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, 1, 3}, 
   Mesh -> {15, 3}], 
  Graphics[
   {Red, PointSize[Medium], 
    Point /@ 
     Table[
      v {Cos[u], Sin[u]}, 
      {u, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/8}, {v, 1, 3, 1/2}]}]}
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use a one-parameter `ParametricPlot` to get the mesh points:

```
p2 = ParametricPlot[ # {Cos[u], Sin[u]} & /@ Range[1, 3, .5], {u, 0, 2 π}, 
   Mesh -> {Range[0, 2 Pi, 2 π/16]}, PlotStyle -> None, 
   MeshStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize[Large]], Axes -> False]
```

[image]

Combine it with the original two-parameter plot using `Show` or using `Epilog`:

```
Show[ParametricPlot[v {Cos[u], Sin[u]}, {u, 0, 2 π}, {v, 1, 3}, Mesh -> {15, 3}], p2]
```

or

```
ParametricPlot[v {Cos[u], Sin[u]}, {u, 0, 2 π}, {v, 1, 3}, Mesh->{15, 3}, Epilog->p2[[1]]]
```

both give

[image]

**Update:** *to see the nodes... sans the surface that spans them*

```
Show[ParametricPlot[v {Cos[u], Sin[u]}, {u, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {v, 1, 3}, 
  Mesh -> {15, 3}, BoundaryStyle -> Gray, PlotStyle -> None], p2]
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to avoid repetition of parametrization with a single function definition? The aim of my question is to see the nodes... sans the surface that spans them.

Comment: @Narasimham, `pp2` gives just the nodes.

Comment: Indeed. Just wanted to see small circles at the nodes generated using ParametricPlot3D as well.