# How to concatenate nodes

Tags: plotting

In my previous question [Small circles at mesh nodes](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/102120/125), I wanted to show mesh intersection points by a tiny red dots on a surface produced by `ParametricPlot`. The accepted answer produced

[image]

The current question is a generalization of the same problem to 3D, namely, how can I show the mesh intersection points with red dots on a surface generated by `ParametricPlot3D`?

The following (hope self explanatory) code is not successful in attempting to show beads/points with curvilinear parametric lines *only,* drawn on the 3D parametrized surface.The surface itself need not be drawn. Not necessary to use Co-catenate command between nodes.

```
 n=5;coord3D={v Cos[u],v Sin[u],u+v};
        ParametricPlot3D[coord3D,{u,0,2 Pi},{v,1,4},Mesh->{3 n,n},Epilog->{PointSize@.02,Red,Point@Catenate@Array[Function[{{u,v},coord3D}],
        {3n+2,n+2},{0,2 Pi},{1,3}]}]
```

Please help to indicate a better way towards the same.. Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: I'm sorry, are you new here? Please make the question self contained and clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
n = 5; coord3D = {v Cos[u], v Sin[u], u + v};
g3d = Graphics3D@{Red, Sphere[#, .15] & /@ (Join @@ 
      Array[coord3D /. {u -> #, v -> #2} &, {3 n + 2, n + 2}, {{0, 2 Pi}, {1, 4}}])}
```

[image]

```
Show[ParametricPlot3D[coord3D, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, 1, 4}, Mesh -> {3 n, n}], g3d]
```

[image]

**Update:** *out of the three components (tiny sphere nodes, cocatenated parametric lines and surface) I would like to see only the first two ( without surface)*

```
Show[ParametricPlot3D[coord3D, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, 1, 4}, 
  Mesh -> {3 n, n}, BoundaryStyle -> Black, PlotStyle -> None], g3d]
```

[image]

Comment: Alright up till now. However out of the three components (tiny sphere nodes, cocatenated parametric lines and surface) I would like to see only the first two ( without surface).

Comment: @Narasimham, please consider updating your post in view of Kuba's comment (maybe with little background information and  a link to your other question) so that it can be reopened.

Comment: Thanks.  I made some necessary changes. Anyway your update already gives exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: @Narasimham, I added a few things in your post. If you think my edit is not useful please remove it.

Comment: Your edit is fine and thanks for it.